# sql : How to select the records with the incremental id for rows which having duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this data in my master table

[image]

I want output like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done a wrong things.First name atrribute in your master table must be unique and you must encrypt any information that stored in master table for security reason.
so the conclusion is name in you attribute must be unique and do not same to each other
and the password must be hash using md5 but its have lower security protection or using SHA or MCyrpt to security issue.

Comment: yes you are right, but i am just giving an example. And by the way, in master table, there may be an possibility that two persons name are similar. But that is another issue.

Comment: I just want to tell from above post that, i want to give incremental id for the duplicate rows.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below query for output as shown in above question.

```
SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name,role ORDER BY name) AS Counter from MasterTable
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: you have asked question and you are answering it. What exactly running in your mind .Please see the guide lines of Stackoverflow